# How connect the community user with User-Password Flow via REST API?

Tags: community, rest-api, oauth2, user, security-token

I'm newbie in SalesForce development and need to get access to community pages using the User-password login. I already got access with this flow using a common user to authenticate. In this case, I'm using a CORS server to avoid use the security token.

I need to use the REST API to integrate with a mobile application, but reading about it, I could't get more detailed information.

If somebody already done that, please help me. If it's not possible, I'll try another solution, but I need access the communities using the REST API.

I changed the URL to the community login, as explained in docs. But I receive an error:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
```

My server is allowed to access using the User-Password flow with the following CURL requisition:

```
curl https://<login server>/services/oauth2/token --request POST --data "grant_type=password&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&username=<username>&password=<password_without_security_token>" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

Regards,
Alexandre

Comment: Community user isn't the same type of user of a SalesForce user. I'm trying to authenticate the contact on community using API. Right now, I can access with common user.

Comment: I don't believe your issue is a duplicate, as I encountered the same problem and the "duplicate" question is not the resolution.  This is not a technical/coding issue, it's Salesforce policy issue.   Namely, community users cannot use the username/password OAuth flow.  This isn't stated in the REST API documentation that I found but it is in the remote access documentation.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5  It's also contradicted by a posting from 2013 stating that flow is available for Portal users.